# How to make interactive web pages within a single page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, single-page-application

For example [this site](http://kabulportraits.nfb.ca/main.html) stays within `main.html` even when clicking within the page. What is the process to keeping everything within the page that shows/hides different elements?

Using Bootstrap by the way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use jQuery to show and hide various divs based on timers or user click events.

For example you could have this HTML

```
<div id="home">Hello. <a href="#" onclick="gotoPage2(); return false;">Page 2</a></div>
<div id="page2" style="display:none;">Page 2. <a href="#" onclick="gotoHome(); return false;">return Home</a></div>

<script>
    function gotoPage2() {
        $("#home").hide();
        $("#page2").show();
    }

    function gotoPage2() {
        $("#page2").hide();
        $("#home").show();
    }
</script>
```